# What happened to colspan='*'?

Tags: html, html-table

There once was a very handy construct: `colspan='*'` meaning "span this column and all the rest of the columns to its right in this table." The production now gives an error in the [html validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

I'm too lazy to count by hand all the columns to be spanned: that's what software is *for*, after all.

What's the modern equivalent of `colspan='*'`, if any?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "now gives an error"?  HTML 4 arrived in the 1990s and even then according to the DTD at http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html specified colspan as requiring a number.

Comment: Jeez, I dunno. Maybe it was 3.2. I've used it successfully but not for a while. It drives me crazy when useful features are discarded. Dang!

Comment: Do you mean `colspan="0"`? [From research](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp) this is not supported well, but is in documentation.

Comment: @Ribose -- Yes, thanks, I think I must mean that. Jukka gave a nice answer to the question [over here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.infosystems.www.authoring.html/browse_thread/thread/c1afce7192f44100/9f665212852ce631?hl=en#9f665212852ce631).